# Debug Pointer Arithmetic

Tags: c, pointers

I am unable to resolve why am I finding difference when I print the difference between the address of variable

Here is the code :

```
int main()
{

        int *a,b = 5,e = 0;
        int *c,d = 10,f = 0;
        long t1,t2;
        a = &b;
        c = &d;
        e = &b;
        f = &d;
        t1 = e - f;
        t2 = a - c;
       printf("\n Address of b using a: %x \t %d using e : %x \t %d value of b : %d",a,a,e,e,b);
       printf("\n Address of d using c: %x \t %d using f : %x \t %d value of d : %d",c,c,f,f,d);
       printf("\n Value of t1 : %d",t1);
       printf("\n Value of t2 : %d \n",t2);
}
```

And here is the output :

```
 Address of b using a: bf9e9384   -1080126588 using e : bf9e9384  -1080126588 value of b: 5

 Address of d using c: bf9e9380   -1080126592 using f : bf9e9380  -1080126592 value of d: 10


 **Value of t1 : 4
 Value of t2 : 1**
```

Why is there a difference between t1 and t2 when theyare assigned to the similar difference

Please let me know .

Comment: doesn't even compile here, how can you assign an int* to an int (e = &b)?

Comment: @stijn: You can, at least in C99 (haven't checked other standards).

Comment: IIRC GCC will warning with this, always use -Werror and -Wall to catch dumb things like that.

Answer (score 8):

`a` and `c` are pointers, so taking the difference of pointers returns the *number of elements* in between them.  `e` and `f` are integers (whose values are simply the addresses of `b` and `d`); taking the difference of integers is literally just a subtraction, so it returns the *number of bytes*.

**Note (1):** The behaviour that results from taking the difference of two pointers that don't point to elements of the same array is *undefined*.

**Note (2):** The behaviour that results from assigning an address to an `int` is *implementation-defined*.

**Note (3):** The difference of two pointers is of type `ptrdiff_t`, whose size is *implementation-defined*.  Therefore, assigning this to a `long` is also *implementation-defined*.

**Note (4):** It's considered pretty bad practice to mix the declarations of pointers and non-pointers on the same line (e.g. `int *a,b = 5,e = 0;`), as it's incredibly confusing!

Comment: Perhaps should add that strictly speaking pointer arithmetic is only defined for items within an array (or the address immediately following an array).

Comment: @Disptick: I was *just* thinking of adding that!  Answer will be updated shortly...

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing different values is that `e-f` is `int` arithmetics, whereas `a-c` is `int*` arithmetics. In `int*` arithmetics, the difference is the number of `ints` that could be placed between the two pointers, so the result is 4 times less with 4-byte ints.

This said, subtracting two pointers that do not point inside the same array is called "undefined behavior" and in theory anything could happen.

Comment: Yup Got the concept Thank you